# Execute JavaScript before Ajax redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, redirect, cookies

Ajax request, redirect to /foo.jsf

```
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  ExternalContext ec = context.getExternalContext();
  ec.redirect("/foo.jsf");
  context.responseComplete();
```

The ajax response:

```
<partial-response id="j_id1"><redirect url="/foo.jsf"></redirect></partial-response>
```

Adding cookies to response will not work for ajax.
I need browser to execute a script to set cookies before redirect,  so need to add `<eval>` before `<redirect>` as following

```
<partial-response id="j_id1"><eval>script_set_cookies</eval><redirect url="/foo.jsf"></redirect></partial-response>
```

How to add `<eval>` before `<redirect>`?  Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just set cookies straight on the response?

Comment: For ajax,  setting cookies on the response wont work.